# Connect Directly to Pluggable Database

Tags: oracle

How I can connect to Pluggable Database Directly?
I'm trying this.

`sqlplus scott/tiger@pdborcl;`

But I'm getting **ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

After that I tried to add localhost.

`sqlplus scott/tiger@localhost/pdborcl;`

Then I got

**ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor**

But when I connected as **System**, then I can easily connect using.

`sqlplus scott/tiger@pdborcl;`

Please help me I really want to get rid of System login again and again.

**#TNSNAMES.ora File**

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\OracleHome\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

PDBORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
    )
  )
```

## SQLNET

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\OracleHome\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

**tnsping pdborcl**

[image]

Comment: Try add USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_listener=on to listener.ora. And what is result for lsnrctl status?

Comment: @hinotf how to find that status?

Comment: Type lsnrctl status in command line

Comment: I got allot of lines,, and in the one line,, I got STATUS Unknown.

Comment: What is status for pdborcl? And what result for "tnsping pdborcl" command?

Comment: @hinotf image added in question.. Please check...

Answer (score 1):

You basically need a couple of items to be in place before a direct connection to a pluggable database can be established.
Ensure the pluggable database is started and open, there is a tnsnames.ora entry for the pdb, confirm the listener has picked up the tnsnames entry for the pdb after you added it, reload the listener configuration if already running.
If you have issues connecting to the pdb using different users, check for permission differences between them.

Comment: so how do you e.g. "Ensure the pluggable database is started and open" ?